# If $Ax=0$ then does the RREF have a row of zeros?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant, solution-verification

> If $\det(A)=0$, then the homogeneous system $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions.

The statement is true. Am I right to say if $\det(A)=0$, then the reduced row echelon form of $A$ has a row of zeros, hence $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions?

Comment: Your reasoning is fine.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask is it true that det(A)=0 if and only if the reduced row echelon form of A has a row of zeros? Do I have the "if and only if"?

Comment: Yes, it is if and only if.

Comment: You might be interested in all the forms of [the invertible matrix theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem) - the statements here are (the contrapositives of) those statements